# Isolating a part of text file using grep

Tags: grep

I have a big file like this small example:

```
chr1    HAVANA  transcript  69091   70008   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000335137.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F5-001"; level 2; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS30547.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001094.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000003223.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    69091   70008   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000335137.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F5-001"; exon_number 1;  exon_id "ENSE00002319515.1";  level 2; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS30547.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001094.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000003223.1";
chr1    HAVANA  CDS 69091   70005   .   +   0   gene_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000335137.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F5-001"; exon_number 1;  exon_id "ENSE00002319515.1";  level 2; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS30547.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001094.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000003223.1";
```

Each line starts with "`chr`". I want to make a new file in which the 3rd column is "`CDS`". How can I do the conditional and `grep`? I used the following code:

```
grep -i CDS infile.txt > outfile
```

but this one returns any line with `CDS` regardless of column number. Do you know how to fix it?

I want to get this from the small example:

```
chr1    HAVANA  CDS 69091   70005   .   +   0   gene_id "ENSG00000186092.4"; transcript_id "ENST00000335137.3"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "OR4F5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "OR4F5-001"; exon_number 1;  exon_id "ENSE00002319515.1";  level 2; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS30547.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000001094.1"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000003223.1";
```

Comment: How are the columns separated?

Answer (score 1):

The clean solution is to explicitly check the third column, with awk:

```
awk '$3 == "CDS"' infile.txt
```

For your limited sample, it looks like all the `CDS` matches on other lines are part of a longer word, so

```
grep -w 'CDS' infile.txt
```

would work as well by requiring the match to be the exact word, but that's only based on the limited sample you show.

A grep solution that checks the third column could look like this (requires GNU grep for `\s`, `\S` and `\>`):

```
grep -E '^(\S+\s+){2}CDS\>' infile.txt
```

or POSIX conformant:

```
grep -E '^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){2}CDS([[:blank:]]|$)' infile.txt
```